# Thymeleaf error when validating form inputs before posting to Api

Tags: java, spring, validation, thymeleaf, spring-validator

This is the error I'm getting (note: errors **are** being caught):

**Browser**: `Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring4.processor.attr.SpringInputGeneralFieldAttrProcessor' (forms/frmEntry:75)`

**STS IDE**: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'e' available as request attribute at 
org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:144) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
....
....`

The `GET` method (displays the form):

```
@RequestMapping(value="/create", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String create(Model model){

    model.addAttribute("entry", new EntryForm());

    return "forms/frmEntry";
}
```

Since my original `POST` method didn't work, I tried creating another, thinner `POST` method just to exclude other code related to `postToEntity` call to Api.

```
@PostMapping("/temp")
public String temp(@Valid @ModelAttribute EntryForm e, BindingResult bindingResult){

// returns 1 in debug mode (error for the only field (name) in the form, so OK
//      int ct = bindingResult.getErrorCount();

    if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){

        // this Thymeleaf view/template is reached
        return "forms/frmEntry";
    }

    // dummy Thymeleaf view (doesn't exist)
    return "proslodokraja";
}
```

My form:

```
<form action="/consumer/temp" th:object="${e}" method="post" class="col-md-6">
    // in my code, this hidden field is commented out (for now)
    <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}" />
    <p>
        Name: <input type="text" th:field="*{name}" class="form-control" />
        <br/>
        <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('name')}" th:errors="*{name}">Name error</span>
        </p>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" /> 
            <input type="reset" value="Reset" class="btn btn-default" />
        </p>
</form>
```

The form `Bean`:

```
public class EntryForm {

private Long id;

@NotNull
@Length(min=2) // hibernate import!
private String name;


public EntryForm(){ }

public EntryForm(String name) { this.name = name; }

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in your model attribute name. You set it as a "entry", then you're trying to access "e" model attribute (which is not even set) in your `frmEntry` form. Rename your model attribute to either "e" when setting it or rename it to "entry" on `frmEntry` page and explicitly provide name in `@ModelAttribute`:

```
<form action="/consumer/temp" th:object="${entry}" method="post" class="col-md-6">


@ModelAttribute("entry") EntryForm e
```

Comment: Not quite. I had replaced `entry` to `e` just before I posted the question, because I was trying to adjust it in accordance to some code snippet from Spring. But just to make sure, I just reverted to `entry` both in template and post method and as expected, the error remained.

Comment: I guess you were right after all. I forgot to change back to `entry` in my `GET` method as well. Finally, I decided to reference the form bean as `entryForm` and it started to work finally. I'm accepting your answer. Thank you for your help!